# How can I use LookerSDK 4.0 to download a tile from a dashboard with filters applied in Python?

Tags: python, sdk, imagedownload, looker

I need to download some specific elements(charts and tables) from a looker dashboard programmatically in python. I am currently exploring the LookerSDK 4.0 to achieve my use case.

I followed these examples to download a dashboard with filters applied and downloading a tile separately.
https://github.com/looker-open-source/sdk-codegen/tree/main/examples/python

I have tried updating the dashboard by applying filters,

```
sdk = looker_sdk.init40("../../looker.ini")

# get dashboard using its id 
dashboard = sdk.dashboard(id)

filters = dashboard.dashboard_filters
for filter in filters:
     if filter["name"] == "user_id":
        filter["default_value"] = "abc"
        break
dashboard.dashboard_filters = filters

# gets updated dashboard with filters
dashboard = sdk.update_dashboard(id, dashboard)
```

Then get the tile using the dashboard based on the tile name,

```
title = title.lower()
found = None
for tile in dash.dashboard_elements:
      if tile.title.lower() == title:
        found = tile
        break
```

And then downloads the tile,

```
task = sdk.create_query_render_task(
    query_id=tile.query_id, 
    result_format=format,
    width=600, 
    height=600
    )
# code to poll the render task until it completes
...
...
...

fileName = "test.png"
with open(fileName, "wb") as f:
    f.write(result)
```

When I try to update the dashboard filters and download the tile, it is still downloading the tile image without filters. Can anyone help me understand how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the resolution to the above problem I was facing. We need to update the dashboard with the specific filters and then fetch the tile.

```
# create the dashboard filter object.
updated_filter = models.WriteDashboardFilter(
    default_value="<value to be updated>",
    model="<model name>",
    name="<field name>",
    type="<field type>"
)

# update dashboard with filter
sdk.update_dashboard_filter(dashboard_filter_id, updated_filter)
```

You can then use the updated dashboard object to get the specific tile. Use create_dashboard_element_render_task instead of create_query_render_task.

```
# create a dashboard element task to render tile to an image/document
task = sdk.create_dashboard_element_render_task(
    query_id=tile.query_id, 
    result_format=format,
    width=600, 
    height=600
    )
```